# Interactively selecting two points from a variable set of plots

Tags: r, shiny

I've been trying to develop a Shiny app to do de following:

Input data set with the following structure: a column called weekna with labels of the xaxis and a variable number of columns with different names that have different values.

My goal is, for each column with values, to interactively ask the user to select two points, one called first and another one called last.

When the user ended entering the points, to make some calculations and print some results.

Additional features:
- Each time the user select a point, it is coloured in the plot (red for first, blue for last).

My intention is:

1. Show the graph for the first column, allow to select first, last point.
2. Plot each point with a different colour in the graph.
3. Print them in a summary table below the plot.
4. Show a button called "Next plot", to go to the second column and repeat the process until the last one is done.
5. Alternatively, use "Previous/Next" buttons to go forward/backward.
6. Alternatively, use tabset with different plots for different columns.
7. Have a final "process" button that shows the results.

My work so far: I've achieved to plot all the graphs in the same frame (not a frame per plot) and placed a final table with the results (in this case to simplify things, I've just arranged the points and show what the user have clicked). I've tried to colour points, but seems it does not remember the previous selection.
Also, I've duplicated each graph, because I dont know how to get two points from the same graph.

Any help in any (or all) of my issues will be welcomed.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("maintab"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 12,
           tableOutput("results_final")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  inputdata<-data.frame(weekna=letters[1:20])
  inputdata$weekno=1:NROW(inputdata)
  inputdata$normal<-dnorm(inputdata$weekno,10)
  inputdata$beta<-dbeta(inputdata$weekno, 1, 1)
  inputdata$gamma<-dgamma(inputdata$weekno, 1, 1)
  inputdata$logistic<-dlogis(inputdata$weekno,10)
  inputdata$poisson<-dpois(inputdata$weekno, 2)
  namescol<-names(inputdata)[-(1:2)]
  nnamescol<-length(namescol)
  for (s in namescol) eval(parse(text=paste0("inputdata$'",s,"_color'<-'1'")))

  makeReactiveBinding('inputdata')

  output$maintab <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      do.call(column, c(width=6,
                        c(
                          lapply(namescol,function(s){
                            call("plotOutput", outputId=paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_first"),
                                 height = 300, click = paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_first_click"))
                          }),
                          lapply(namescol,function(s){
                            call("tableOutput", outputId=paste0("results_",as.character(s),"_first"))
                          })
                        )[c(rbind(1:nnamescol,1:nnamescol+nnamescol))]

      )),
      do.call(column, c(width=6,
                        c(
                          lapply(namescol,function(s){
                            call("plotOutput", outputId=paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_last"),
                                 height = 300, click = paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_last_click"))
                          }),
                          lapply(namescol,function(s){
                            call("tableOutput", outputId=paste0("results_",as.character(s),"_last"))
                          })
                        )[c(rbind(1:nnamescol,1:nnamescol+nnamescol))]

      ))
    )
  })

  lapply(namescol, function(s){output[[paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_first")]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(inputdata, aes_string("weekno", s, color=paste0(s,"_color"))) + geom_point() + geom_line(color="#000000") +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=inputdata$weekno, labels = inputdata$weekna)+
      labs(title = s, x = "week", y = "rate")
  })})

  lapply(namescol, function(s){output[[paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_last")]] <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(inputdata, aes_string("weekno", s, color=paste0(s,"_color"))) + geom_point() + geom_line(color="#000000") +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=inputdata$weekno, labels = inputdata$weekna)+
      labs(title = s, x = "week", y = "rate")
  })})

  lapply(namescol,function(s){
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_first_click")]], {
      np <- nearPoints(inputdata, input[[paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_first_click")]], maxpoints=1 , threshold = 1000)
      output[[paste0("results_",as.character(s),"_first")]] <- renderTable({
        data.frame(var1=s,np[c("weekno","weekna",s)],stringsAsFactors=F)
      })
      inputdata[,paste0(as.character(s),"_color")] <<- rep("1",length(inputdata$weekno))
      inputdata[inputdata$weekno==np$weekno,paste0(as.character(s),"_color")] <<- "2"

      output$results_final <- renderTable({
        out1<-data.frame()
        for (s in namescol){
          sname<-paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_first_click")
          np<-nearPoints(inputdata, input[[sname]], addDist = F, threshold=1000, maxpoints=1)
          if (NROW(np)==0){
            out1x<-as.data.frame(t(rep(NA,4)),stringsAsFactors=F)
          }else{
            out1x<-data.frame(var1=s,np[c("weekno","weekna",s)],stringsAsFactors=F)
          }
          names(out1x)<-c("var1","weekno_first","weekna_first","value_first")
          out1<-rbind(out1,out1x)
        }
        out2<-data.frame()
        for (s in namescol){
          sname<-paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_last_click")
          np<-nearPoints(inputdata, input[[sname]], addDist = F, threshold=1000, maxpoints=1)
          if (NROW(np)==0){
            out2x<-as.data.frame(t(rep(NA,4)),stringsAsFactors=F)
          }else{
            out2x<-data.frame(var1=s,np[c("weekno","weekna",s)],stringsAsFactors=F)
          }
          names(out2x)<-c("var1","weekno_last","weekna_last","value_last")
          out2<-rbind(out2,out2x)
        }
        out3<-data.frame(var1=namescol)
        outf<-merge(out3,out1,all.x=T, by="var1")
        outf<-merge(outf,out2,all.x=T, by="var1")
        outf
      })

    })
  })

  lapply(namescol,function(s){
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_last_click")]], {
      np <- nearPoints(inputdata, input[[paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_last_click")]], maxpoints=1 , threshold = 1000)
      output[[paste0("results_",as.character(s),"_last")]] <- renderTable({
        data.frame(var1=s, np[c("weekno","weekna",s)],stringsAsFactors=F)
      })
      inputdata[,paste0(as.character(s),"_color")] <<- rep("1",length(inputdata$weekno))
      inputdata[inputdata$weekno==np$weekno,paste0(as.character(s),"_color")] <<- "3"

      output$results_final <- renderTable({
        out1<-data.frame()
        for (s in namescol){
          sname<-paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_first_click")
          np<-nearPoints(inputdata, input[[sname]], addDist = F, threshold=1000, maxpoints=1)
          if (NROW(np)==0){
            out1x<-as.data.frame(t(rep(NA,4)),stringsAsFactors=F)
          }else{
            out1x<-data.frame(var1=s,np[c("weekno","weekna",s)],stringsAsFactors=F)
          }
          names(out1x)<-c("var1","weekno_first","weekna_first","value_first")
          out1<-rbind(out1,out1x)
        }
        out2<-data.frame()
        for (s in namescol){
          sname<-paste0("plot_",as.character(s),"_last_click")
          np<-nearPoints(inputdata, input[[sname]], addDist = F, threshold=1000, maxpoints=1)
          if (NROW(np)==0){
            out2x<-as.data.frame(t(rep(NA,4)),stringsAsFactors=F)
          }else{
            out2x<-data.frame(var1=s,np[c("weekno","weekna",s)],stringsAsFactors=F)
          }
          names(out2x)<-c("var1","weekno_last","weekna_last","value_last")
          out2<-rbind(out2,out2x)
        }
        out3<-data.frame(var1=namescol)
        outf<-merge(out3,out1,all.x=T, by="var1")
        outf<-merge(outf,out2,all.x=T, by="var1")
        outf
      })

    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

EDIT:

Today I have been thinking on my problem and I have a plan:

To create two datasets that must be reactive (with makereactivebinding) and can be updated interactively.

plotdataset: the same as input with another column for each column of the original dataset called as the original plus _color.

clickdataset: a data.frame that stores all the clicks in all the plots along with the time the click is done.

The plan is:

Use plotdataset to plot each original column along with the respective _color column to plot the two points in two different colors (name red/green)
use a tabsetpanel to plot a set of panels, each one with a different column.

Each time the user click anything, the clicked point is added with rbind to the  clickdataset.

Select the lastest two clicked points of each column in the clickdataset and order them to find out the first/last point.

update with this information the plotdataset _color column, so that the first is "red" and the last is "green", so that all plots are updated.

Selecting the lastest two clicked points of each columns allows the user to click three, four times if he doesnt like the selection, updating everytime to the lastest two clicks.

Now it is time to think on how to implement my plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just programmed what I outlined this morning as my plan to solve this problem.

This is the result, with this procedure i can get any number of points from a single plot.

I've simplified the problem by not allowing the input dataset to have a variable number of columns (I've made an example with two columns only), but to adapt this example to a more general case should be easy seeing my original code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

inputdata<-data.frame(weekno=1:20, weekna=letters[1:20])
inputdata$normal<-dnorm(inputdata$weekno,10)
inputdata$beta<-dbeta(inputdata$weekno, 1, 1)
inputdata$gamma<-dgamma(inputdata$weekno, 1, 1)
inputdata$logistic<-dlogis(inputdata$weekno,10)
inputdata$poisson<-dpois(inputdata$weekno, 2)

tail.order<-function(i.data, i.n, i.order){
  res<-tail(i.data, n=i.n)
  res<-res[order(res[i.order]),]
  res$id.tail<-1:NROW(res)
  res
}

extract.two<-function(i.data, i.order, i.column){
  data<-unique(i.data, fromLast=T)
  results <- do.call("rbind", by(data, data[i.column], tail.order, i.n=2, i.order=i.order))
  return(results)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("maintab")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  origdata<-inputdata[c("weekno","weekna","normal","poisson")]
  plotdata<-origdata
  namescol<-names(plotdata)[-(1:2)]
  nnamescol<-length(namescol)
  for (s in namescol) eval(parse(text=paste0("plotdata$'",s,"_color'<-'1'")))

  values <- reactiveValues(plotdata = plotdata, clickdata=data.frame())

  output$maintab <- renderUI({
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("normal", plotOutput("plot_normal"
                                              , click = paste0("plot_normal_click")
    )),
    tabPanel("poisson", plotOutput("plot_poisson"
                                   , click = paste0("plot_poisson_click")
    )),
    tabPanel("results",tableOutput("results")),
    tabPanel("resultsfull",tableOutput("resultsfull"))
    )
  })

  output$plot_normal <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(values$plotdata, aes_string("weekno", "normal")) +
      geom_point(aes_string("weekno", "normal", color="normal_color")) +
      scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "grey", "2" = "red", "3" = "green")) +
      geom_line(aes_string("weekno", "normal"), color="#000000") +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=origdata$weekno, labels = origdata$weekna)+
      labs(title = s, x = "week", y = "rate")
  })

  output$plot_poisson <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(values$plotdata, aes_string("weekno", "poisson")) +
      geom_point(aes_string("weekno", "poisson", color="poisson_color")) +
      scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "grey", "2" = "red", "3" = "green")) +
      geom_line(aes_string("weekno", "poisson"), color="#000000") +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=origdata$weekno, labels = origdata$weekna)+
      labs(title = s, x = "week", y = "rate")
  })

  output$results<-renderTable({
    if (NROW(values$clickdata)>0) extract.two(values$clickdata,"weekno","variable")
  })

  output$resultsfull<-renderTable({
    values$clickdata
  })

  observeEvent(input$plot_normal_click, {
    np <- nearPoints(origdata, input$plot_normal_click, maxpoints=1 , threshold = 1000)
    values$clickdata<-rbind(values$clickdata,data.frame(variable="normal", np, stringsAsFactors = F))
    if (NROW(values$clickdata)>0){
      p0<-extract.two(values$clickdata,"weekno","variable")
      p1<-subset(p0, variable=="normal" & id.tail==1)
      p2<-subset(p0, variable=="normal" & id.tail==2)
      if (NROW(p1)>0) {
        values$plotdata[values$plotdata["normal_color"]=="2","normal_color"]<-"1"
        values$plotdata[origdata$weekno==p1$weekno,"normal_color"]<-"2"
      }
      if (NROW(p2)>0){
        values$plotdata[values$plotdata["normal_color"]=="3","normal_color"]<-"1"
        values$plotdata[origdata$weekno==p2$weekno,"normal_color"]<-"3"
      }
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$plot_poisson_click, {
    np <- nearPoints(origdata, input$plot_poisson_click, maxpoints=1 , threshold = 1000)
    values$clickdata<-rbind(values$clickdata,data.frame(variable="poisson", np, stringsAsFactors = F))
    if (NROW(values$clickdata)>0){
      p0<-extract.two(values$clickdata,"weekno","variable")
      p1<-subset(p0, variable=="poisson" & id.tail==1)
      p2<-subset(p0, variable=="poisson" & id.tail==2)
      if (NROW(p1)>0) {
        values$plotdata[values$plotdata["poisson_color"]=="2","poisson_color"]<-"1"
        values$plotdata[origdata$weekno==p1$weekno,"poisson_color"]<-"2"
      }
      if (NROW(p2)>0){
        values$plotdata[values$plotdata["poisson_color"]=="3","poisson_color"]<-"1"
        values$plotdata[origdata$weekno==p2$weekno,"poisson_color"]<-"3"
      }
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```